# Hyperledger Fabric : Impact on transaction when we migrate Orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Migration of Ordering service from Kafka to Raft.
As we understand the Ordering service never signs the transaction in Fabric. Dose this migration will effect anything on old transaction ordered by old ordere?

Also when we query transaction(local peer query), why do we set the orderer flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have successfully migrated consensus type from kafka >> raft

You are allowed to proceed with transactions.

Question1: `Ordering service never signs the transaction in Fabric`

Endorsing peers alone will sign transactions & orderer signs the blocks

Question2: `Dose this migration will effect anything on old transaction ordered by old ordere?`

No, If migration is successful then you are OK to proceed

If you would have followed this link and complete without errors https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka_raft_migration.html

THEN OK, dont worry about previous data, All SAFE.

However, let me know if you need any assistance in migration. Feel free to create another question reg: migration.

If you want to see old blocks after migration
check this snippet

```
// keep the block_reg to unregister with later if needed
block_reg = channel_event_hub.registerBlockEvent((block) => {
    console.log('Successfully received the block event');
    <do something with the block>
}, (error)=> {
    console.log('Failed to receive the block event ::'+error);
    <do something with the error>
},
    {startBlock:23}
);
```

startBlock:{can be any Block No}

check > https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html

you will get complete block as json format, you will have orderer signature so that you can check which orderer has sealed this block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, Will try the migration on demo network, however i still have 1 more question.
If we have a business requirement to validate the block created by old orderer, how this process will work?

Comment: `If we have a business requirement to validate the block created by old orderer` >>>>>   Means that you want to see the block whats inside? What is definition of validation in your POV

Comment: We want to know which orderer had signed the block by verifying its signature.

Comment: Oh, gotcha, what you can do is once network migration is completed you can get old blocks as a json format check this https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html, using this you can get previous blocks which generated by kafka >>> see my above answer is updated with snippet

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped :)

Comment: Happy Hyperledger!! Anytime I will help you

Comment: @NarendranathReddy is it possible to backup the data from one Network to another network with different MSP ca certs e.t.c ?
should i create a new question regarding this ?

Comment: @AdarshaJha didn't get you